# Как правильно сказать волноваться за что, волноваться о чём, волноваться чего?

Tags: грамматика, др.-русский

Я посмотрел в Яндекс переводчике
есть:
Волноваться нечего.
Это не то, о чем тебе стоит волноваться
Не волнуйтесь за меня.
пожалуйста, можно объяснить разницу?

Answer (score 1):

> пожалуйста, можно объяснить разницу?

Попробую.

> Я посмотрел в Яндекс переводчике есть:

Это плохой источник.

> Волноваться нечего.

Это правильная разговорная конструкция, но у неё другой смысл. "Нечего" означает "не надо", "не стоит", "нет причин". Глагол "волноваться" не управляет этим местоимение. 
Сравните: "Нечего сидеть сложа руки", "Чего уставился?" и проч.

> Это не то, о чем тебе стоит волноваться

Это правильный литературный вариант. Речь идет о неодушевленном предмете или объекте.
**"Волноваться о чем".**

> Не волнуйтесь за меня.

Тоже правильно, с легким налетом разговорности. Речь идет о человеке, **"волноваться за кого"**

Словарь управлений в русском языке дает оба варианта как равноправные:

> ВОЛНОВАТЬСЯ [беспокоиться] за кого-что / о ком-чём. 
>   Волноваться за сына; Волноваться за исход дела; Волноваться о
>   родителях; Волноваться о судьбе книги.

Но на мой взгляд значения у єтих конструкций слегка расходятся. "Волноваться о ком/чем" - означает "активное" волнение, сопряженное с некоторыми действиями, "за кого/что" - скорее пассивное волнение, связанное с какими-то событиями, которые субъект не контролирует или будущие.

Таким образом, в первую очередь можно рекомендовать ***"волноваться о чем" и "волноваться за кого".***